# Render Div based on custom cookie in AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

i need to render a one div based on custom cookie with condition

i have a cookie on different location like asia, africa etc

now i want to render the div based on that location cookie

```
<div class="counrty-div" >
  <amp-country-div class="country-div" width="16" height="13"></amp-country-div>
</div>
```

i tried with `amp-access` but i am able to add condition correctly

can any one help me to how to achieve this

Comment: Have you tried to use amp-geo?

Comment: @MilindMore when  i work on code which in playground which you share [link](https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-geo&format=websites&_gl=1) i cannot able set hide based on country code can you help me with code , and another thing thing is even after i tried by using vpn it show only country where i am in it did not show the vpn server country